# Using Insert and Update in a single function

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if someone would be able to shed some light on how I may overcome this problem.

I'm trying to add and update information on a database, so when a user first enters completes the questionnaire its fine and it works, However when they go back to update the questionnaire **it throws an error**, "Please go back and try again".

I have updated the PHP code with the recommendations given to me so far.

Thank You.

PHP code:

```
function updatePartCTQ_part1($questionAns, $memberid) {

//First Insert MemberID
$ctqmemberinsert = "INSERT INTO ctq_questionnaire (user_id) VALUES ('$memberid')";
$addresult = mysqli_query($ctqmemberinsert);

if ($addresult) {

    $update = "UPDATE ctq_questionnaire SET Item1= '{$questionAns[0]}', Item2 = '{$questionAns[1]}' WHERE user_id = '$memberid'";

    mysqli_query($conn, $update);

} else {
    echo 'Please go back and try again';
}
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Finished Code**

Thanks to Michael and the rest of the guys I was able to get the code working, so I thought I'd post an update, if anyone else gets stuck they'd be able to have a glance at the working version of the code:

```
function updatePartCTQ_part1($questionAns, $memberid) {

//Check whether user exists
$exists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ct1_questionnaire WHERE user_id = '$memberid'");

if (mysql_num_rows($exists) === 0) {
    // Doesn't exist. INSERT User into Table

    $ctqmemberinsert = "INSERT INTO ctq_questionnaire (user_id) VALUES ('$memberid')";
    mysqli_query($ctqmemberinsert);
} 
    // UDPATE after INSERT

    $update = "UPDATE ctq_questionnaire SET Item1= '{$questionAns[0]}', Item2 = '{$questionAns[1]}, Item3 = '{$questionAns[2]}',  
    Item4 = '{$questionAns[3]}',Item5 = '{$questionAns[4]}', Item6 = '{$questionAns[5]}', Item7 = '{$questionAns[6]}', 
    Item8 = '{$questionAns[7]}', Item9 = '{$questionAns[8]}', Item10 = '{$questionAns[9]}', Item11 = '{$questionAns[10]}', 
    Item12 = '{$questionAns[11]}', Item13 = '{$questionAns[12]}', Item14 = '{$questionAns[13]}', Item15 = '{$questionAns[14]}'
    WHERE user_id = '$memberid'";

    mysql_query($update);
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't use array indices when using a variable in a string like that. Try concatenation instead.

Comment: @Gigi Well, then, you remember incorrectly. :)

Comment: @Gigi It will work, though is preferred to enclose them in `{}` as `{$questionAns[0]}`

Comment: @Nerd-Herd, I was about to say the same thing lol.

Comment: To OP: With that `try...catch` scenario, all you're doing is just inserting values.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd so it'll be best to remove the try...catch

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated mysql_ functions. They are old and deprecated. See the red box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` syntax is incorrect. You must not repeat the `SET` keyword:

```
$update = "UPDATE ctq_questionnaire SET Item1= '{$questionAns[0]}', Item2 = '{$questionAns[1]}' WHERE user_id = '$memberid'";
//-------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^ no SET here
```

For readability it is recommended to enclose the array values in `{}`, although your way should work.

Note that your `try/catch` isn't going to be of much use since `mysql_query()` does not throw an exception. Instead it will just return `FALSE` on error.  Instead, store it in a variable and test for `TRUE/FALSE` as you did with the `INSERT`.

```
// We assume these values have already been validated and escaped with mysql_real_escape_string()...
$update = "UPDATE ctq_questionnaire SET Item1= '{$questionAns[0]}', Item2 = '{$questionAns[1]}' WHERE user_id = '$memberid'";
$upd_result = mysql_query($update);
if ($upd_result) {
  // ok
}
else {
  // error.
}
```

Finally, and I suspect you've heard this before, the old `mysql_*()` functions are scheduled for deprecation. Consider moving to an API which supports prepared statements, like MySQLi or PDO.

#### Update

Assuming you have a unique index or PK on `ctq_questionnaire.user_id` on subsequent calls, the first query will error and your second won't be run. The simplest fix is to use `INSERT IGNORE`, which will treat key violations as successful.

```
$ctqmemberinsert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO ctq_questionnaire (user_id) VALUES ('$memberid')";
```

A more complicated solution is to first test if the username exists in the table with a `SELECT`, and if not, do the `INSERT`.

```
$exists_q = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM ct1_questionnaire WHERE user_id = '$memberid'");
if (mysql_num_rows($exists_q) === 0) {
  // Doesn't exist. Do the INSERT query
}
// proceed to the UDPATE after INSERTing if necessary
```

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I didn't know that about the functions, I guess I'll go back and change them, and yes the values have been validated using a seperate function

Comment: @StrangeLondoner See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php for your options.

Comment: I've updated the code, and tried to explain further the trouble I'm facing with it, just wondering if you could take a look.

Comment: Thank You so much it worked like a charm. I should have realised before to check whether the user exists. But thank you nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your insertion to this:

```
$ctqmemberinsert = "INSERT INTO `ctq_questionnaire` (`user_id`, `Item1`, `Item2`)
    VALUES ( '$memberid', '" . 
        mysql_real_escape_string($questionAns[0]) . "', '" . 
        mysql_real_escape_string($questionAns[1]) . "' )";
```